# Azure Devops Pipeline - Variable file based on branch

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to have different variable template files that would be used based on the branch being built? I was trying to do something like this:

```
jobs:
- job: BuildandPublish
  variables:
    - template: /env/$(Build.SourceBranchName).vars.yml
```

But that doesn't work, I'm guessing do to the order that those variables are replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have different variable template files that would be used based on the branch being built?

From your YAML sample, you are using the format: `$(Build.SourceBranchName)`. The variable value will be expanded at runtime.

But the template will read the variable at Compile time.

To solve this issue, you need to change the format : `${{ variables['Build.SourceBranchName'] }}`

Here is an example:

```
jobs:
- job: BuildandPublish
  variables:
    - template: /env/${{ variables['Build.SourceBranchName'] }}.vars.yml
```

Comment: Thanks. I had tried similar syntax based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch but it didn't work. I had tried ${{ variables.Build.SourceBranchName }}

Comment: we can also use the standard naming process in the environment variable and link to pipeline and use it to replace step using Build.SourceBranchName , ex - dev-tokenname, uat-tokenname